# Missing sal.h while compling a win32 project via mingw

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, mingw, winapi

Error message:

> fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory cstudy  line 11, external
>   location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\specstrings.h  C/C++ Problem.

But when I add VC/include to this project,I received a ton of  error messages. It seems VC/include/sal.h is not a standard header file for GCC.

The source code is very simple:

```
#include "windows.h"
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{

    return 0;
}
```

Environment:

- Windows 7.0A SDK
- VC 2010
- MINGW
- CDT/ECLIPSE.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to compile windows code in mingw? You should probably use the visual studio compiler to do so.

Comment: Have you installed the MinGW WIN32 API package? Also, you should be using `#include <windows.h>` as it's a system header file.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `sal.h` header is **not** part of GCC / MinGW, however you can add your `VC/include/` as an include directory to eclipse.

*alternative:* move *all* (!) requried headers to your mingw or project `include` directory. The one from MinGw is: `<mingw path>/include`).

> Anyway. sal.h, if you install the Windows SDK then it isn't going to
>   be in the SDK directory, but you should find that if you select to
>   install the compiler and tools it will get installed along with that.
>   This is because sal.h is needed in the CRT headers as well as the
>   Windows headers. So you NEED to install the VS compilers and tools
>   along with the SDK. You will then find that the compiler will be
>   installed by default under %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2010\VC and sal.h will be in include under that path. On 64 bit
>   systems it will be under %ProgramFiles(x86)% by default.

<sub>*source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowssdk/thread/0e166050-99f1-436b-bd94-b39e2910f43d*</sub>

**See:**

- [can't find sal.h](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowssdk/thread/0e166050-99f1-436b-bd94-b39e2910f43d) **(!)**
- [Windows SDK header files question](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Windows-SDK-header-files-question-td5870336.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  I can't seem to get the sal.h header file through the MS Windows version of mingw, but "yum whatprovides \*/sal.h" on my Fedora Core 18 machine brought up the mingw-headers package.  I downloaded the source package (i.e. yumdownloader --source mingw-headers), opened up the .tar.gz file in file-roller, grabbed the sal.h file, and put it in /c/MinGW/include on my MS Windows machine.

The same package had dsound.h, which was the next missing header file.

I've never tried to use mingw under Fedora Core to cross-compile MS Windows apps, but maybe it's time... :-)